# How to synchronise two databases that have used by two diffrent application

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, cakephp

I have two application

Application A - Database A and Application B - Database B

Applications are php based using mysql as database.Both database have a table with name 'user'.I want to synchronize this user table so that when end user update information application A it should be reflect into Application B.

Now one more concern in this case is that application A has encrypted data and Application B have plain database.And also both application are on different network.

I am thinking about -

1) database replication ( not sure it will work due to encryption or not)
2) use of web services
3) A cron file that will update both database after some interval.

I want to what is the best and why . If is there any other to do this then also please reply with that.

Thanks

Comment: use transactions and replication

Comment: Cron will be the great option for this.

Comment: @Robert can we use these if one table is encrypted and other table is not

Comment: It will be better if you maintain an intermediate table to log the changes from both the application in one of the database. Then have a cronjob to read the log table and update the appropriate database table. Because comparing both user table and updating might be costlier operation.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a single signon where they are automatically logged in to both systems with the same credentials?

Comment: @BryanWaters yes some thing like that but i can not keep one common table for both application. I have to create two different

Answer (score 0):

Replication is not going to help you out here very much as the table structures are different.  An approach I've used before to tie together two systems like this is to write a small api wrapper around the new account, update, login and logoff process.

Then when user creates a new user or logs in or logs off or updates application A then you can issue a curl https call via php from server A to your api on Application B and update the state over there.  If you can expose the same subdomain on both applications ie,  appA.mydomain.com and appB.mydomain.com they can even share cookies which makes single login and logoff easier as your api integration can set the proper logon cookies for both applications at the same time.

You'll have to dig in a little bit on how ApplicationB works to build your api wrapper, but you can reuse any encryption functions, etc already present.